# Can electron automatically figure out whether to use HTTP or HTTPS given a URL without a protocol?

Tags: node.js, http, https, electron

Given an arbitrary URL without a protocol, such as www.google.com, Chrome will attempt to use https, and if https is unavailable it will fall back to http. I'm using electron and would like to take advantage of this feature in chrome. How can I retrieve the absolute URL, including the protocol, from a BrowserWindow after calling `browserWindow.webContents.loadURL('www.google.com');`?

Answer (score 0):

Electron seems to *not* supplement your URL with a possible protocol. If you don't provide protocol, you get 'invalid url' error (in `6.0.1`)

Anyway, you can get the full URL with `getURL`

```
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron')

app.once('ready', () => {
  const win = new BrowserWindow()
  win.loadURL('www.google.com')
    .then(() => {
      console.log('ready', win.webContents.getURL())
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err)
    })
})
```